# Anyone know how to sell CartThrob Credits?

Tags: add-on, cartthrob

I just love asking stupid questions, but I'm on a deadline and can't find any documentation on how to enable users to purchase CartThrob Credits. The description says you can, and I suspect it's really obvious, but I'm stumped.

Comment: Have you bought the [CartThrob Credits](http://cartthrob.com/site/product_detail/credits) addon?

Comment: Hey, Taz, any chance you can respond or let us know if this Jason was correct in that you don’t have CartThrob Credits installed?